# Scrape data-encoded-url from website with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I try to scrape the restaurant websites on [www.tripadivisor.de](http://www.tripadivisor.de)

For example I took this one:
[Restaurant](https://www.tripadvisor.de/Restaurant_Review-g187367-d12632224-Reviews-Leni_Liebt_Kaffee-Aachen_North_Rhine_Westphalia.html) and on the site there is a reference to my URL I want to scrape: http://leniliebtkaffee.de

The source code looks like this:

```
    <a data-encoded-url="VUxRX2h0dHA6Ly9sZW5pbGllYnRrYWZmZWUuZGUvX3FLOQ==" class="_2wKz--mA _27M8V6YV" 
    target="_blank" href="http://leniliebtkaffee.de/"><span class="ui_icon laptop _3ZW3afUk"></span><span 
    cass="_2saB_OSe">Website/span><span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box _2OpUzCuO"></span></a>
```

However, if I try to scrape this with the following python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.tripadvisor.de/Restaurant_Review-g187367-d12632224-Reviews-Leni_Liebt_Kaffee-Aachen_North_Rhine_Westphalia.html'  
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    for website in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'_2wKz--mA _27M8V6YV'}):
        print(website)
```

I get

```
<a class="_2wKz--mA _27M8V6YV" data-encoded-url="NVh0X2h0dHA6Ly9sZW5pbGllYnRrYWZmZWUuZGUvX1dDWg==" target="_blank"><span class="ui_icon laptop _3ZW3afUk"></span><span class="_2saB_OSe">Website</span><span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box _2OpUzCuO"></span></a>
```

Unfortunately, there is no href link in there. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a URL base64-encoded in `data-encoded-url`:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode(b"NVh0X2h0dHA6Ly9sZW5pbGllYnRrYWZmZWUuZGUvX1dDWg==")
b'5Xt_http://leniliebtkaffee.de/_WCZ'
```

As you can see, the URL seems to be padded with either nonsense or some kind of flags, so you'll want to strip that.